# 12th consecutive TRUE row in data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

How to find 12th consecutive TRUE value in $crit? I am tryng with something like this:

```
    for(i in 12:nrow(df)) {
    if(sum(df$crit[(i-12):i])=12)
    print(df$date[i])
    }
```

Is this code ok for looping over groups of 12 consecutive rows?

My data:

```
date                   rain temp rh accumulation  crit
1  2015-04-02 10:00:00  0.5  9.8 96           NA FALSE
2  2015-04-02 11:00:00  0.1 10.0 95           NA  TRUE
3  2015-04-02 12:00:00  0.0 10.1 95           NA  TRUE
4  2015-04-02 13:00:00  0.1 10.7 95           NA  TRUE
5  2015-04-02 14:00:00  0.0 10.7 94           NA  TRUE
6  2015-04-02 15:00:00  0.1 10.7 95           NA  TRUE
7  2015-04-02 16:00:00  0.6 11.2 96           NA  TRUE
8  2015-04-02 17:00:00  0.1 11.7 96           NA  TRUE
9  2015-04-02 18:00:00  0.4 11.6 96           NA  TRUE
10 2015-04-02 19:00:00  0.2 11.3 96           NA  TRUE
11 2015-04-02 20:00:00  0.6 11.3 97           NA  TRUE
12 2015-04-02 21:00:00  0.2 11.6 97           NA  TRUE
13 2015-04-02 22:00:00  0.0 12.0 96            1  TRUE
14 2015-04-02 23:00:00  0.3 11.8 96            2  TRUE
15 2015-04-03 00:00:00  0.0 11.8 97            3  TRUE
16 2015-04-03 01:00:00  0.0 11.9 97            4  TRUE
17 2015-04-03 02:00:00  0.1 12.2 95            5  TRUE
18 2015-04-03 03:00:00  0.8 11.4 93            6  TRUE
19 2015-04-03 04:00:00  0.6 10.9 92            7  TRUE
20 2015-04-03 05:00:00  0.0 10.3 89           NA FALSE
```

Comment: Maybe you want the `rle` function, which summarises runs of repeated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a rolling sum - you want to add up the last 12 `crit` values and see if you get 12 or not. There's a lot of ways to do a rolling sum, but a particularly easy one to implement is a lagged `cumsum`.

```
## some data
set.seed(47)
crit = runif(100) < 0.8 

## rolling sum of last 12 elements
rs = cumsum(crit) - cumsum(c(rep(0, 12), head(crit, -12)))

## see where we get to 12
which(rs == 12)
# [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 62 63 64 65 66

## verify
names(crit) = seq_along(crit)
crit[16:29]
#    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Hopefully the code is pretty easy to understand. In the verify step we can see that indeed the 28th element (first output of the `which`) is the 12th in a series of 12 `TRUE`s.

---

Translating to a data frame application:

```
set.seed(47)
dd = data.frame(crit = runif(100) < 0.8, date = as.Date("2016-01-01") + seq_along(crit))    

rs = with(dd, cumsum(crit) - cumsum(c(rep(0, 12), head(crit, -12))))

dd[which(rs == 12), ]
#    crit       date
# 28 TRUE 2016-01-29
# 29 TRUE 2016-01-30
# 30 TRUE 2016-01-31
# 31 TRUE 2016-02-01
# 32 TRUE 2016-02-02
# 33 TRUE 2016-02-03
# 34 TRUE 2016-02-04
# 62 TRUE 2016-03-03
# 63 TRUE 2016-03-04
# 64 TRUE 2016-03-05
# 65 TRUE 2016-03-06
# 66 TRUE 2016-03-07
```

---

### Edit 2: More explanation

To understand the rolling sum, let's do a simple example of less than 12 - say we want to know the sum of the last 3 elements. Your data is already simple in that it just has TRUE and FALSE for the column we're summing, but for shortness of printing I'll use 1 and 0.

```
ex = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

The `cumsum` function gives the cumulative sum of all the elements so far. We can think of the `i`th element of `cumsum(ex)` as `c_ex[i] = sum(ex[1:i])`

```
(c_ex = cumsum(ex))
# [1]  1  1  2  3  3  3  4  5  6  6  7  8  9 10
```

A rolling sum is like a cumulative sum, but we don't want to keep everything until the end of the vector, just the last few elements. If we have the rolling sum of 3 elements of `ex`, `rs_ex`, we could write the `i`th element as `rs_ex[i] = sum(ex[(i - 2):i])`. This is very similar to what you have in your code in the question (though do note that `i-2, i-1, i` make three elements, so we do want to start with `i - (n - 1)` for a window of size `n`.

Since addition is nicely commutative, we can break up the rolling sum and rewrite it as `rs_ex[i] = sum(ex[1:i]) - sum(ex[1:(i - 3)])`. In words, if we want to know the sum of elements 8, 9, and 10, and we already know the cumulative sums, we can take the cumulative sum of elements 1 to 10 and subtract the cumulative sum of elements 1 to 7. What's left is the sum of elements 8, 9 and 10.

For things to line up nicely with the original data, we create a dummy vector that's identical to the original vector, but with `n` zeroes stuck on the front (and the last `n` elements cut off the end), and the `cumsum` of that we can subtract off the `cumsum` of the original to get the rolling sum.

```
#                             add three 0s at front,   chop off last three elements
rs_ex = cumsum(ex) - cumsum(  c(rep(0, 3),             head(ex, -3)))
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 3 2 2 2 3 3
```

And that gives us the rolling sum of the last three elements.

Going back to your original example, if you need to work with this much, just add it to your data. If your data frame is called `dd`, do

```
dd$rs = with(dd, cumsum(crit) - cumsum(c(rep(0, 12), head(crit, -12))))
```

And then you can continue to work with the data frame using the rolling sum information, e.g.,

```
subset(dd, rs == 12)
```

to see all the rows where the last 11 values and the current value for `crit` are all `TRUE`. If you need all rows +/- 3 from the rows where `rs == 12` then one way to find them is this

```
rs12 = which(rs == 12)
rs12_pm3 = 1:nrow(dd) %in% c(rs12, rs12 + 1, rs + 2, rs + 3, rs - 1, rs - 2, rs - 3)
dd[rs12_pm3, ]
```

There's maybe better and more generalizable ways, but that should work for a small window like 3.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I have tried rle and cumsum (although did not quite get to your 12h code, thanks), but it gives me only part of solution because I am looking to get only 12th hour mark, which would trigger next criteria... and how do I actually apply "rs" to my data frame to identify these values? Obviously coming from excel environment and still trying to wrap my head around R environment.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "*I am looking to get only 12th hour mark, which would trigger next criteria*", but I'll edit to add a data frame example.

Comment: I have edited the data frame. steps: 12th consecutive hour with criteria met, then look if there was rain in +/-3 hours, if yes, start accumulation of hours until criteria is met, if no start from 16th hour, again until criteria is met.

Comment: I mean, that doesn't sound like anything in your question. Maybe you should ask a new question as it seems like your original question has been answered?

Comment: Thanks, Gregor, it seems like it is answered but I will have to ask anew question it is getting to complex for me. Could you please just add some more description on the code for rolling sum of last 12 elements.

Comment: a new one: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699305/conditional-sums-in-data-frame-r)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have crit like :

```
crit<- c(FALSE, rep(TRUE,12),FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,rep(TRUE,12))

> crit
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[17]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

if you check the first 12 values, which include 1 False and 11 TRUE, you get:

```
> x <- rle(crit[1:12])
> x
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:2] 1 11
  values : logi [1:2] FALSE TRUE
```

if you check from 2:13, which are all TRUE, you get:

```
> x
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int 12
  values : logi TRUE
```

then if you check if all are true, you can check as follows by using mean:

```
> mean(x$values==TRUE)
[1] 1
```

so if you intend to check 1:12, 13:24, start:end...etc. you can check:

```
x <- rle(crit[start:end])
```

then

```
mean(x$values==TRUE)
```

if it is equal to one, you confirm that you have 12 consecutive TRUE.